# program is running fine but cannot being import with IndexError

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7, the following is the simplified version of my script:

executor.py

```
import sys 

def someCal(num):

        num = int(num)
        print num*num

someCal(sys.argv[1])
```

so `python executor.py 13` would print out 169, it's working as expected.
and I have another script, I want to make use of `someCal()` function in `executor.py` so I import it

main.py

```
import executor

to_count = 999
executor.someCal(to_count)
```

I got the error message below when execute `python main.py`:

```
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import executor
  File "/Users/mac/executor.py", line 13, in <module>
    someCal(sys.argv[1])
```

I don't know why it keep mentioning about line 13 in executor.py, because I didn't use that part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey,could you check an answer as correct answer please, it may help for future users who will see your question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from executor import *
```

It is a better method and will work fine as you wanted.No need *if **name** == '**main**':* with this method. Also you can call your functions with their names.Like:

```
from executor import *
print (someCal(10))
```

**Edit for example:**

> executor.py

```
def someCal(num):
    num = int(num)
    return num*num
```

> another.py

```
from executor import *

print (someCal(10))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
100
>>>
```

If you working with functions, you should *return* a value in function, not print. If you *return* a value, you can print it later.But if you dont use *return* and just keep it like *print num*num*, then you cant use it later with print function. You can try and see that.So, returning a value is important in functions.

> **For your second question**, check this one: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Python is the best language about clear codes, so you should keep it clear, *sys* is not necessary for you. And you dont need *if **name** == '**main**':* this statement, remember every .py file is a module, so if you can import any module without that statement,like *import random*; then you can import your own modules too.Just care about they have to stay in same directory so Python can find your own module/file. Keep it simple :-)

> **Another import method for a module is**:

```
import executor as ChuckNorris

print (ChuckNorris.someCal(10))
```

Output is same of course, you can write whatever you want instead of *ChuckNorris*, but be sure that name doesnt overlap with another function name in your program. For example you have a .py file called Number.py, you will import this file to another file, but you cant be sure is there any function called *Number* in another one, so you can call it like *import Number as whatyouwanttocallit* and you will avoid from that problems.

Comment: hi @qqvc I tried it but doesn't work, still see the exact same error message

Answer (score 2):

When you `import executor` in *main.py*, it actually doing `python executor.py`, I suggest you change your *executor.py* to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        someCal(sys.argv[1])
```

and, you might want to add defensive code like `if len(sys.argv)>1` before use `sys.argv[1]` directly

Comment: It seems to work! but what does if __name__ == '__main__' means?

Comment: @b937r977 "is this file the main file?"