# Python cannot import name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't seem to figure out how to import two classes to each other. When running the application it simply says

```
  from room import Room
ImportError: cannot import name Room
```

It might be a design problem but I don't think there's another way to reference the two classes, so this needs to be as it is. The only reason the imports are needed is because they are required by the redisco module in the objects (they need to know the types)

```
#Room class.

class Room(models.Model):
    from player import Player
    players = models.ListField(Player, required = True)

#Player class
class Player(models.Model):
    from room import Room
    room = models.ReferenceField(Room, required = True)
```

How do I get this to work?

E:

The framework is [Redisco](https://github.com/iamteem/redisco) (Redis)

Comment: Solution: put them in the same file.

Comment: Does ReferenceField accept a string instead of an object? At least SQLAlchemy does. @nbro: That's a dirty workaround.

Comment: You mean you want a *backreference* here?

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's probably also fast. If also both classes are really related to need one another, it would also be the best solution

Comment: What framework is this? Are you using Django perhaps?

Comment: Putting them in the same file is really a no go sorry. This is redisco (redis) so yes you can store ints, strings etc etc. It's just easier to work with references rather than querying all the time. I don't know what a backreference is sorry.

Comment: Move the imports out of the class definitions. If they're in the same file you only need one before the first class referencing `Room`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ORM models either support back references (where the target model of a reference field is given an extra attribute that points back to the referencing object), and / or lets you specify relationships through other means.

Redisco doesn't have back-references that I could discover, but it *does* support string references. If you pass in a string it'll be interpreted as a model name, matched against the `__name__` attribute:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    players = models.ListField('Player', required = True)
```

This neatly bypasses the import problem altogether.

From the [`ListField` docstring](https://github.com/kiddouk/redisco/blob/269a3b9affe299814162369ed4fbebf2c927b77c/redisco/models/attributes.py#L248-L259):

> target_type -- can be a Python object or a redisco model class.
>
> If target_type is not a redisco model class, the target_type should
>       also a callable that casts the (string) value of a list element into
>       target_type. E.g. str, unicode, int, float.
>
> ListField also accepts a string that refers to a redisco model.

The [code to resolve the name](https://github.com/kiddouk/redisco/blob/269a3b9affe299814162369ed4fbebf2c927b77c/redisco/models/attributes.py#L297-L304) uses the function [`get_model_from_key()`](https://github.com/kiddouk/redisco/blob/fc141d86071aaf86e62282f1e64e8d1721da4287/redisco/models/base.py#L713-L720) to resolve the string, which simply searches through all subclasses of `models.Model`, matching on `__name__`.

It'll resolve the name when validating new values or when retrieving existing values for the first time, by which time the `Player` subclass has already been imported.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in the same .py file then you don't need imports. If they are in different files in the same directory just use 'import room' (assuming its in a file called 'room.py'). If they are in separate files in separate directories you will need to use the imp module.

```
import imp
roomClass = imp.load_source('roomClass', [Path to room.py])
```

Then it can be called with something like:

```
aRoom = roomClass.Room(Model)
```

Comment: Depending on the framework, there are better ways to handle this; SQLAlchemy for example takes **string references**.

Comment: Following the imp way it results in the same error I suspect the original way did. Infinit recursion: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Answer (score 0):

> First of all if you want to import a module to your program, they must be in the same directory.

Follow this for importing modules ;

```
from filename import classname
```

> Which is the *filename= your .py file* that you want to import class
>
> *class* is the specific class that you want to use.

**Or**;

```
from filename import *
```

> Which is going to add all functions and classes.
>
> Also check this topic. [program is running fine but cannot being import with IndexError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664543/program-is-running-fine-but-cannot-being-import-with-indexerror/27664558#27664558)

Answer (score -1):

You can reference to this problem.

[Pythonic way to resolve circular import statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748946/pythonic-way-to-resolve-circular-import-statements)

Using `import` rather than `from [...] import [...]`

Comment: The `Player` class still won't be defined at that time, because the `class` body hasn't been executed yet.